# Translating from Natural Language to Propositional Language

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

I'm struggling a bit with this logic problem:

I have been asked to translate the following sentences into propositional language.

- Pliny is happy and Quintilian is happy.
- If Pliny is happy then either Quintilian or Rufina is happy.
- If neither Pliny nor Quintilian are happy then Rufina is happy.

I think the first line would be $P\land Q$? But not sure of the other two.

Does anyone have an idea? Would really appreciate any help. Thanks everyone

Comment: "either Quintilian or Rufina is happy" will be $Q \lor R$.

Comment: "If Pliny is happy then ..." will Be $P \to \ldots$.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA it depends on whether the meaning of "either" is inclusive or (which is what you assumed) or exclusive or, which what "either" usually means.

Comment: @Χpẘ - it is clear that the OP is "struggling" with formalization in prop logic. Following the comments and the answer she can try to answer to translate the original sentence, using the "appropriate" connectives according to the textbook/lectures she is using.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA good point. But why give the asker the extra burden of figuring out that $\lor$ may be the wrong connective. You could at least point out that two connectives are possible.

Answer (score 5):

First, you suggest propositions, but you need to define them explicitly.  We will need three propositions:

$P:$ Pliny is happy.

$Q:$ Quintilian is happy.

$R:$ Rufina is happy.

So you are given:

$(1)\;$ Pliny and Quintilian are happy.

$(2)\;$ If Pliny is happy, then Quintilian is happy or Rafina is happy.

$(3)\;$ If neither Pliny nor Quintilian is happy, then Rafina is happy.

1. $\;P \land Q$
2. $\;P\to (Q\lor R)$
3. $\;(\lnot P \land \lnot Q)\to R$

Answer (score 0):

Looks like first line indeed is $P \text{ and } Q$, while second is $P \implies Q \text{ or } R$. Can you do the rest?

Comment: "either" usually means exclusive or.

Comment: @Χpẘ  Please do not confuse the OP.  There is nothing that mandates the use of the exclusive or, when one says "either x or y".

Comment: @AmWhy there's the meaning of the English language. Since this is an assignment for the OP, the teacher grading the assignment may very well use the standard definition of either/or which Senex posted below.

Comment: Xpw That is not a standard definition. So sorry to tell you.

Comment: @AmWhy What is "the standard definition", via reference please?